# parallel camera in i.mx6QUAD

Tags: linux, camera, imx6

I am using i.m6QUAD with hummingboard2 (hummingboard Gate) with 3.14.79 linux kernel from this site GitHub - SolidRun/linux-fslc: Linux kernel source tree

It's been a loong time since i am playing with ov5642 parallel camera and I can't get it to work...

As i see on schematic of hummingboard I can use parallel camera using IPU2_CSI1.

I set up device tree as this:

-in file "imx6qdl-hummingboard2.dtsi" (this file contains common part fo quad and dual-lite) I set up v4l2 to use IPU2/CSI1:

```
v4l2_cap_0 {
        compatible = "fsl,imx6q-v4l2-capture";
        ipu_id = <1>;   //default was <0>
        csi_id = <1>;   //default was <0>
        mclk_source = <0>;
        /*mipi_camera = <1>; */
        /*default_input = <0>; */
        status = "okay";
    };
```

---

-Then in file "imx6q-hummingboard2.dts" I add following settings:

```
&iomuxc{
hummingboard2{
pinctrl_hummingboard2_parallel: hummingboard2_parallel{
fsl,pins= <                                                           //SHOULD BE fsl,pins or different ??
MX6QDL_PAD_EIM_A24__IPU2_CSI1_DATA19 0x0b0b1
MX6QDL_PAD_EIM_A23__IPU2_CSI1_DATA18 0x0b0b1
MX6QDL_PAD_EIM_A22__IPU2_CSI1_DATA17 0x0b0b1
MX6QDL_PAD_EIM_A21__IPU2_CSI1_DATA16 0x0b0b1
MX6QDL_PAD_EIM_A20__IPU2_CSI1_DATA15 0x0b0b1
MX6QDL_PAD_EIM_A19__IPU2_CSI1_DATA14 0x0b0b1
MX6QDL_PAD_EIM_A18__IPU2_CSI1_DATA13 0x0b0b1
MX6QDL_PAD_EIM_A17__IPU2_CSI1_DATA12 0x0b0b1
MX6QDL_PAD_EIM_DA11__IPU2_CSI1_HSYNC 0x0b0b1
MX6QDL_PAD_EIM_DA12__IPU2_CSI1_VSYNC 0x0b0b1
MX6QDL_PAD_EIM_A16__IPU2_CSI1_PIXCLK 0x0b0b1

MX6QDL_PAD_EIM_DA10__GPIO3_IO10 0x400130b1  //pwn
MX6QDL_PAD_EIM_DA15__GPIO3_IO15 0x400130b1 //rst
>;    
};
};
}; 

&i2c3{
ov5642: ov5642@3c{
compatible = "ovti,ov5642";
reg = <0x3c>;
clocks = <&clks IMX6QDL_CLK_CKO2>;
clock-names = "csi_mclk";

pwn-gpios = <&gpio3 10 GPIO_ACTIVE_LOW>;
rst-gpios = <&gpio3 15 GPIO_ACTIVE_LOW>;
ipu_id = <1>;  //the same as in v4l2
csi_id = <1>;  //the same as in v4l2
mclk = <24000000>;
mclk_source=<0>;   //the same as in v4l2

pinctrl-names = "default";
pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_hummingboard2_parallel>;

};
};
```

When I reboot my system and do "sudo modprobe ov5642_camera" i got in "dmesg":

"pin MX6Q_PAD_EIM_A24 already requested by 20e0000.iomuxc; cannot claim for 2-003c. "

The same error is for other pins dafined in "pinctrl_hummingboard2_parallel"

But when I change "fsl,pins" to "fsl,ipu" error disapears but gstreamer shows only a black screen and after some while turns off. Pipeline I use:

gst-launch-1.0 imxv4l2videosrc device=/dev/video0 imx-capture-mode=3 ! decodebin ! autovideosink

dmesg messages when I use "fsl,pins" are shown in attached pisture "fls,pins-dmesg" and when I use "fsl,ipu" in picture "fsl,ipu-dmesg".

Can someone hepl me to run this camera ??[image: fsl-ipu-dmesg]
[image: fsl,pins-dmesg]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. The solution was obious  - to remove used pin defclaration in imx6qdl-hummingboard2.dtsi file. However I don't know why in my first try of removing pins my linux didn't want to boot up (so I rejected this solution as not working).